# how can i fix my bath tub

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water

When I turn the water on to take a bath the water don't run it just drips and takes hours to fill the tub or I have to add pots of water is there a way for this to be fixed or do I have to call a plumber.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Ensured all the shutoffs are open?  Does the cold run at proper pressure or does it affect both hot/cold? Are there other fixtures nearby and do they work as-expected?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few factors that could be effecting the water flow to your tub. Some of these include pinched plastic type water line, low water pressure, shredded seals inside a single handle mixer valve, excessive mineral deposit in the faucet, debris  deposit inside your water line such as fine sand or other particulate, possibly even a totally clogged water filtration system or a non functioning water softener.

If you are unsure about trying to isolate what, if any of these possible causes, could be the problem with your system then you would be best advised to call in a professional plumber.